# Не могу составить запрос к мускулу, я сутки уже мучаюсь

Tags: запрос, mysql

Здравстуйте.

Помогите пожалуйста в составлении запроса.
есть три таблицы, две из них в join вот так:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM
table1 t1,
table2 t2 
WHERE
t1.id1 = t2.id2
limit 10
```

нужно добавить третью таблицу так чтобы для каждой записи был счетчик

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as mycount FROM table3 t3 WHERE t3.target_id = t1.id
```

и по нему добавить условие

```
mycount > 2
```

и сортировку

```
order by mycount DESC
```

я сделал только через having, но explain запроса сказал мне что нужно переделать.
прошу помощи.

т.е. составить один запрос из трех таблиц, причем по третьему запросу нужно подсчитать и получить на выходе и количество и сортировку по этому полю и ещё условие по нему

Comment: Где Вы учились sql?! Сами говорите Join, а пишите ужас.  
  
FROM  
table1 t1 **Inner Join** table2 t2 **ON** t1.id1 = t2.id  
  
Не правильней ли запись? Вы когда программируете соблюдаете этикет (отступы, комментарии, адекватные названия переменных и прочее...)? Так тут тоже есть свои правила.

Comment: а разве перечисление через запятую не есть join ом? есть, только синтаксис on, using меняется к конструкции where.
для муксула именно так.

Comment: >    а разве перечисление через запятую не есть join ом?  

Это декартово произведение кортежей, в котором потом WHERE оставляет нужное.  
Во всех SQL языках подобные конструкции... И люди не зря придумали эти самые Join_ы_  
А для предложения WHERE всегда найдётся что написать.

Comment: т.е вы хотите сказать конструкция
SELECT t1.*
FROM
table1 t1
INNER JOIN
table2 t2 
ON
t1.id1 = t2.id2
limit 10

будет на порядок быстрее чем эта:

SELECT t1.*
FROM
table1 t1,
table2 t2 
WHERE
t1.id1 = t2.id2
limit 10

?

Comment: Написание кода соблюдая отступы будет на порядок быстрее? Я говорю как правильней, а не как быстрее...

Comment: """Не правильней ли запись?""
так чем правильней? чем правильней указывать так как вы написали?

Comment: @nikita_sergeevich Запись через запятую - это краткий вид "inner join"... Есть во многих СУБД...

Comment: Через запятую - это устаревший, что естественно, стандарт SQL-89. Табличные выражения с join ввел стандарт SQL-92

Answer (score 1):

Например так:

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) cnt
    FROM
      table3 t3
    WHERE
      t3.target_id = t1.id
    HAVING
      cnt > 2
  ) mycount
FROM
  table1 t1,
  table2 t2
WHERE
  t.id1 = t2.id2
ORDER BY
  mycount
LIMIT 10
```

Или так:

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  t3.count
FROM
  table1 t1,
  table2 t2,
  (
    SELECT
      target_id,
      COUNT(*) mycount
    FROM
      table3
    GROUP BY
      target_id
    HAVING
      mycount > 2
  ) t3
WHERE
  t1.id1 = t2.id2 and
  t3.target_id = t.id
ORDER BY
  t3.mycount
LIMIT 10
```